# Sequelize get sum of columns from association tables

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

I have two tables

`CustomerAccount` and `CustomerAccountService`

They are related in the following way:

```
CustomerAccount.hasMany(CustomerAccountService, {
    foreignKey: 'account_uuid'
});

CustomerAccountService.belongsTo(CustomerAccount, {
    as: 'account',
    foreignKey: 'account_uuid'
});
```

CustomerAccountService has two columns named invoice_amount and core_amount.

I want to get list of all CustomerAccount and within that list I want to show the sum of all invoice amounts and all core amounts for its children CustomerAccountService records.

This is the query I am trying:

```
CustomerAccount.findAll({
    attributes: [
        'uuid',
        'account_name',
        'account_number',
        'emergency_pay',
        [Sequelize.fn('SUM', Sequelize.col('CustomerAccountService.invoice_amount')), 'totalInvoiceAmount'],
        [Sequelize.fn('SUM', Sequelize.col('CustomerAccountService.core_amount')), 'totalCoreAmount']
    ],
    include: [
        {
            model: CustomerAccountService,
            attributes: []
        }
    ],
    group: ['CustomerAccount.uuid']
}).then(...);
```

However it throws an error saying

> Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: Unknown column
>   'CustomerAccountService.invoice_amount' in 'field list'

How do I get the sum of the two columns from the association table?

The model definition for CustomerAccountService is:

```
return sequelize.define(
        'customer_accounts_services', 
        {
            uuid: {
                type: type.STRING,
                primaryKey: true,
                autoIncrement: false
            },
            account_uuid: type.STRING,
            account_number: type.STRING,
            account_type: type.STRING,
            payment_type: type.STRING,
            service_type: type.STRING,
            date: type.DATEONLY,
            description: type.TEXT,
            invoice_amount: type.DECIMAL(10,2),
            core_amount: type.DECIMAL(10,2),
            paid: type.BOOLEAN
        },
        {
            timestamps: false,
            underscored: true,
            tableName: 'customer_accounts_services'
        }
    );
```

Comment: Can you include your schema or model definitions? Does the `invoice_amount` field exist, or is it `invoiceAmount` in the db? You can also add `logging: true` to your query to log the SQL so you can inspect it.

Comment: Yes the invoice_amount and core_amount fields do exist in the model definitions.

Comment: Thanks - posting an answer now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your model definition set the table name to `customer_accounts_services` but you are passing in the Model name of `CustomerAccountService` to `Sequelize.col()`, which does not exist, so you are getting the error about the missing columns.

Update your query to use the correct table name in `Sequelize.col()`.

```
[Sequelize.fn('SUM', Sequelize.col('customer_accounts_services.invoice_amount')), 'totalInvoiceAmount'],
[Sequelize.fn('SUM', Sequelize.col('customer_accounts_services.core_amount')), 'totalCoreAmount']
```

Comment: Got it. I was under the impression that we are suppose to use model. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @codeinprogress generally you should but it's not 100% consistent. glad you got it working!

Comment: on another note (a different questions from the above) - when I try to display the totalInvoiceAmount on the page (using handlebars it does not show up). any idea why it might be happening?

Comment: It's probably not mapped to a model property so you have to access it from the "data values" - `result.getDataValue('totalInvoiceAmount')`. You could also set up VIRTUAL fields that map to the data values and then you can access it directly, but it depends on if it is worth polluting the model properties...